# How to uninstall Carthage from OS X?

Tags: macos, carthage

Somehow, my Carthage installation is corrupted (seems like I have two versions installed) due to the fact that I installed using the `Carthage.pkg` file then also with `brew install carthage`. I'd like to completely remove Carthage(s) but can't find the way to do so.

Answer (score 26):

In order to delete Carthage installed from:

1. **Carthage.pkg**:

   ```
   $ rm -rf /usr/local/bin/carthage
   $ sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/CarthageKit.framework
   ```
2. **Homebrew**:

   ```
   $ brew uninstall --force carthage
   ```

Answer (score 13):

To remove carthage installed by brew:

```
brew uninstall carthage
```

To remove all versions of carthage installed by brew:

```
brew uninstall --force carthage
```

Comment: But how can one uninstall the Carthage.pkg version?

Answer (score 6):

If you installed it via `Carthage.pkg` you can remove it by using the following commands in terminal:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/CarthageKit.framework
unlink carthage
```

To delete it from **Homebrew** you just have to do what Alen Liang provided on his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39864260/2664437):

Comment: Great! Just a note, when I run unlink, it gives me this error: `unlink: carthage: No such file or directory`. Doesn't matter I guess?